# Is there any solution to make columns or grid with different width and different height through bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, grid

Kindly see the image - that's what I want to develop using bootstrap but I am unable to control the height and width difference...

Is there any solution?[image]

Each column have image of full with and 100% height.. Without any JS only through css..

Comment: Also must be responsive.?

Comment: You can use some jquery  plugin for this type of layout

Comment: Use ***[Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/)*** grid layout.

Comment: Masonry grid layout is through js is it can be through CSS only?